# Ansible. Assign pre/post tasks to tag in playbook

Tags: ansible

I described my tags in final playbook in next way:

```
  roles:
    - { role: common, tags: ["common"] }
    - { role: redis, tags: ["redis"] }
```

Beside that in the same playbook I have pre/post task sections:

```
  pre_tasks:
    - include: pre_post_tasks/create_lock.yml

  post_tasks:
    - include: pre_post_tasks/remove_lock.yml
```

The problem is that pre/post tasks launch only with all tags included (w/o tags parameter):

```
ansible-playbook -vv -l host -i inventory/dev --extra-vars '@temporary/additional_inventory' playbook.yml
```

And don't with tags:

```
ansible-playbook -vv -l host -i inventory/dev --extra-vars '@temporary/additional_inventory' playbook.yml --tags "redis"
```

Why? Is it by design? How to avoid this? I want to execute pre/post tasks in all cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like for all tasks, you can use [special tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags). In your case `always`:

```
pre_tasks:
  - include: pre_post_tasks/create_lock.yml
    tags:
      - always

post_tasks:
  - include: pre_post_tasks/remove_lock.yml
    tags:
      - always
```